# Is it possible to show cleaned value on invalid form in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Suppose I have a simple login form with email and password fields.

User enter email 'TEST@EXAMPLE.COM'
And leaved password empty.

I clean email to be lower-cased.

Form is invalid and user is shown form again.

How to show email lower-cased, i.e. test@example.com?

Answer (score 1):

In Django form instance can be either bound or unbound. So what you can do is fetch username from request convert it to lowercase and return bounded form with lowercased username.
FYI

```
def login(request, template_name='login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username').lower()
        pass = request.POST.get('password')
        form = authentication_form(request, data={'username':username, 'password':pass})
        if form.is_valid():
            #Login user and redirect to respective page
        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                                            current_app=current_app)
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)
    context = {'form': form}
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```